# How to play an AnimationClip when key is pressed in Unity3d, C#?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

1. I have tried this code, but it doesn't work.
2. Can someone help me, and can someone explain things about animations in Unity 3D? I have tried so much, google, youtube etc.

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class PlayAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

       public AnimationClip walk;
       Animation anim;

       void Update () {
           if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)){
               anim.clip = walk;
               anim.Play();        
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You're never doing `anim = GetComponent<Animator>();` in the Start-method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the looks of your code you're never actually referencing the attached Animaton on your component. Try assigning anim it's component in the Start method, like this:

```
public class PlayAnimation : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public AnimationClip walk;
    Animation anim;
 
    void Start() 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }
     
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) 
        {
            anim.clip = walk;
            anim.Play();        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have changed it in my script, but it doesn't work. I've got a 3d model with an animator, animation and my script in the inspector. But if I enable the animator, the animation plays all the time and if I release the W button too. If I disable him, there plays nothing.

Comment: May I suggest you check a quick tutorial on Animator, Animatons and how to control them? It's only 8 minutes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeZkctmoBPw and if you've got a somewhat grasp on it you can always watch it on higher speed! How I usually do things is to set up a pattern in the animator, then add variables to the transitions between animation, then control those variables with `animator.setBool("Walk", true);` for instance, thus telling the animator to animate the Walking animation

Comment: Okay, I will check it.

Comment: And sorry for my bad English by the way, I am from the Netherlands.

Comment: niet een probleem. sorry voor bad nederlands!

Comment: I have seen the video, but I don't understand why parameters are useful. Can you explain me that better than the video.

Comment: Oh, ummm... Let's imagine we have a game where the player has 3 animations: Idle, Walk & Run. You can set a parameter float "movementspeed" which will be updated with the speed of the player every Update. In our animator we have `Idle -> Walk -> Run` where the `->` represent a transition based on the movementspeed parameter. When Movementspeed is 0 we show idle, when it's 0><4 we show walk and when it's >5 we transition to Run. You can also control specific transitions between animation when you do it like this, for instance maybe the transition from Walk -> Run should start 50% in on Walk.

Comment: By using parameters we get a dynamic lifecycle of animations. Animation.Play(); (I've never used it but I'm guessing:) just starts the animation on loop? Perhaps not a good example, I don't know. It's the only way I know of doing it, haha.

Comment: How can I do that, that a parameter changes when the speed changes of my character?

Comment: Assuming you have a 2D game and an animator set up with a float parameter called "Movementspeed": in your Update() method you do `animator.SetFloat("Movementspeed", rigidbody.velocity.x);` where animator is an Animator (`animator = GetComponent<Animator>();`) and rigidbody.velocity.x is the speed of the rigidbody in x-axis.

Comment: But the key element here is to do animator.SetFloat("ParamterName", value); every frame so your animator knows the speed of every frame and can choose which animation to play based on the transition conditions.

Comment: I did it, thanks for help. Great and in the Netherlands we say: Top!

Comment: @DaniëlvanderZwan Did this answer solve your question? If it did, be sure to accept it.

Comment: It seems @DaniëlvanderZwan replied with an answer that shows how he solved it, which is great! You should Accept that answer as the answer for people who needs similar help!

Answer (score 5):

The `anim` variable is not initialized. You can initialize it in two ways:

**1**.GetComponent

If the `Animation` component is attached to the-same Gameobject your `PlayAnimation` script is attached to:

```
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
}
```

If the `Animation` component is attached to different Gameobject:

```
void Start()
{
    anim = GameObject.Find("GameObjectAnimationIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Animation>();
}
```

**2**.Make `anim` variable `public` then assign it from the Editor.

`Animation anim;` should be `public Animation anim;`. Now, drag the GameObject with the `Animation` component to the `anim` variable.

Comment: Photo finish on that one, but you  beat me to it! Ha!

Comment: Lol I know. I was typing when I saw your comment so I knew you were going to post. Anyways, +1.

Answer (score 2):

This is my code now and it works, thanks to Frederik.
I got now how the parameters work and the animator.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

public class PlayAnimation : MonoBehaviour {
public Animator animator;
byte idle=0;
byte walk=1;
byte sprint=2;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        animator.SetInteger ("Anumber", walk);
    } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        animator.SetInteger ("Anumber", walk);
    } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        animator.SetInteger ("Anumber", walk);
    } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        animator.SetInteger ("Anumber", walk);
    } else {
        animator.SetInteger ("Anumber", idle);
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for a note, before playing animation in update must check that is not playing. As input runs several time in update

```
   if(!anim.IsPlaying("YourClipName"){
                        anim.clip = walk;
                         anim.Play();
                     }
```